# How to ignore first line of for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, lxml

Using two for loops and getting this result .

```
TABL  1st Line
TABL  
TABL  2nd Line
TABL  3rd Line
```

What i want is:

```
TABL  1st Line
TABL  2nd Line
TABL  3rd Line
```

I am using lxml to fetch data from xml the is something like this.

```
for ent in row.xpath('entry/text()'):
   entry_text+=" "+ent
print("TABL    "+entry_text)
```

Comment: You can avoid selecting empty text node by adding a predicate like so : `row.xpath('entry/text()[normalize-space()]')`

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's an empty/blank data in your list.

You'd be better off with a generator comprehension: you can do the job efficiently (string concatenation is under-performant), and in one line

```
"\n".join("TAB  "+e for e in row.xpath('entry/text()') if e.strip())
```

- loop through the elements as `e`, and only issue something in the iterator if `e` is not empty or only whitespace (given the output we cannot be sure).
- join the result using `"\n"`